# Calculating current school year

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to calculate what the CURRENT school year is, based off of sysdate.

Since academic school years generally run from (approximately) August - May, I need to look at what the current month is to determine which school year we are actually in.

For example, if the current month is May of 2013, then it would be the 2012-2013 school year.  However, if the current month is September of 2013, then it would be 2013-2014 school year.

I suspect my approach is way off and there is a much easier way to accomplish this, but here is the portion of sql code I am working with now:

```
WHERE to_date(ps_customfields.getStudentscf(s.id,'VolTran_ExpDate'),'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN 

CASE 
    WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') < '08' THEN '08/01'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-1) and '08/01/'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') 
    WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') >= '08' THEN '08/01'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') and '08/01/'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')+1)
END
```

The ps_customfields.getStudentscf(s.id,'VolTran_ExpDate') field is a plain text field, which is why I'm casting it as a date.

The error I'm getting in SQLDeveloper with this specific code is "ORA-00905: missing keyword", but I haven't been able to pin down what I'm missing.

Can anybody suggest a more elegant way to accomplish this???

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Result of `CASE` is a value, not range. If I understood the question right you need 2 `CASE`s (also, it seems second `WHEN` can be replace with `ELSE`):

```
WHERE to_date(ps_customfields.getStudentscf(s.id,'VolTran_ExpDate'),'MM/DD/YYYY') 
BETWEEN     
 CASE 
    WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') < '08' THEN '08/01'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-1) 
    ELSE '08/01'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') 
 END
AND
 CASE 
    WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') < '08' THEN '08/01/'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') 
    ELSE '08/01/'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')+1)
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

```
where trunc (add_months (to_date( ps_customfields.getStudentscf (s.id,
                                                               'VolTran_ExpDate'),
                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                         5),
             'YYYY')
      = trunc (add_months (sysdate, 5),
              'YYYY')
```

In other words, add 5 months to both of the dates and compare the years.  Adding 5 months to a date in Jan-Jul doesn't change the year, but adding 5 months to a date in Aug-Dec moves to the next school year.

To be honest the CASE solution is easier to understand, I offer this just for completeness!

Comment: I like this approach...  Yes, it's not quite as intuitive as my original approach, but it's less coding, and honestly, I think it is a more elegant solution.  Thank you very much!  :-D

Answer (score 0):

@a1ex07

Your solution works great! I only had to cast parts of it back to date, so the final version is:

```
WHERE to_date(ps_customfields.getStudentscf(s.id,'VolTran_ExpDate'),'MM/DD/YYYY') 
BETWEEN     
    CASE 
        WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') < '08' THEN to_date('08/01/'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')-1) , 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        ELSE to_date('08/01'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    END
AND
    CASE 
        WHEN to_char(sysdate,'MM') < '08' THEN to_date('08/01/'||to_char(sysdate,'YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        ELSE to_date('08/01/'||(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')+1), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    END
```